# php session lost after header() redirect

Tags: php, session

This is first time i try to create a session.
Also, after success login i redirect the page using header() function, but then on the redirected page i dont have session any more. There is the code:

creating session:

```
function userLogin($user){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
    header("Location: /~klemeno/vaja10?" . SID);
    exit;
}
```

When browser redirect me i try to echo session like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){   
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
}
else{
    echo "No session :(";
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to call `session_start();` in both scripts to start and resume the session.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: i have it, but on wordpress, session not working

Answer (score 1):

You have to add session_start(); at the top of your PHP script(s).